# How do I bind the properties of an object to a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Cell class, with a property called Color, and I make a List of Lists of Cell objects that I plan to use as the binding source for a UniformGrid. The cells in the uniform grid should change color based on the object's Color property, however, no matter how I write the xaml code it doesn't change. I also tried putting the cells in ObservableCollections but it doesn't work, it just shows up as GameOfLife.Cell in the Window.

I have this xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Line">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CellTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
        <DataGridCell Content="{Binding}" Background="{Binding Color}"></DataGridCell>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<UniformGrid Background="Red">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Cells" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Line}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

And this is how I tried to bind the cell objects:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>> cells = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Cell>>();

            cells.Add(new ObservableCollection<Cell> { new Cell(State.Alive), new Cell(), new Cell(State.Alive) });
            cells.Add(new ObservableCollection<Cell> { new Cell(State.Alive), new Cell(), new Cell() });
            cells.Add(new ObservableCollection<Cell> { new Cell(), new Cell(State.Alive), new Cell() });

            Cells.ItemsSource = cells;
        }
```

The implicit state of a cell is State.Dead.

What I want to know is why it doesn't work and how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nested ItemsControls it would be simpler to have a single ItemsControl with a UniformGrid as its ItemsPanel, and e.g. a Border or a Grid to visualize the cell:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/>
                </Border.Background>
                <!-- optional child element here -->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model could look like shown below. Note that the Cell class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to notify about changes of its properties. Unless you want to change the grid size dynamically, you don't need to use an ObservableCollection of Cell object. A plain List is sufficient.

```
public enum CellState
{
    Dead, Active
}

public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private CellState state;
    public CellState State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("State");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return state == CellState.Dead ? Colors.Red : Colors.Green; }
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; } = new List<Cell>();
}
```

and initialized like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        vm.Cells.Add(new Cell { State = i % 3 == 0 ? CellState.Dead : CellState.Active });
    }

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. I am also amazed that you actually guessed a lot of the code I had in my Cell.cs file. 

I would like to ask a bit about the ViewModel class you made, I've seen it before in other pieces of code, does this have to do with the MVVM design pattern, or is this something else? I think I should read about it a bit since I have it in my code now.

Comment: You're right, that's MVVM. Having an instance of a "main" view model class in the DataContext of the MainWindow is the typical architectural pattern of a WPF application.